# ¿Cómo puedo definir observables calculados modificables en Dukescript?

Tags: knockoutjs, dukescript

Estoy tratando de replicar el [ejemplo 1](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html) usando Dukescript.
El ejemplo consiste en que tras la modificación del **nombre completo auto-generado** automáticamente se modifiquen los campos **nombre** y **apellido** del modelo de datos.

Este es el código que llevo hasta ahora

HTML:

```
<div>Nombre: <span data-bind="text: firstName, valueUpdate: input"></span></div>
<div>Apellido: <span data-bind="text: lastName, valueUpdate: input"></span></div>
<div class="heading">Hola, <input data-bind="textInput: fullName, valueUpdate: afterkeydown,event: { keyup: fullName() }
"/></div>
```

Java:

```
package org.javapro.dukescript;

import net.java.html.json.Model;
import net.java.html.json.ComputedProperty;
import net.java.html.json.Property;
import net.java.html.json.Function;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


@Model (targetId="",className = "WritableComputed", properties = {
    @Property (name = "firstName", type=String.class)
   ,@Property (name = "lastName", type=String.class)
})
class MyClass {

  @ComputedProperty static String fullName(String firstName, String lastName) {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
  }

  @Function
  static void fullName(WritableComputed model, String value) {
    int lastSpacePos = value.lastIndexOf(" ");
            // Ignore values with no space character
            if (lastSpacePos > 0) {
              // Update "firstName"
                model.setFirstName(value.substring(0, lastSpacePos)); 
              // Update "lastName"
                model.setLastName(value.substring(lastSpacePos + 1)); 
            }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
    WritableComputed wc = new WritableComputed("hello","world");
    wc.applyBindings();
  }
}
```

El problema es que el campo de texto solamente muestra una función de javascript

> function(c,k){var e=b.ko4j;e&&d.java_lang_Class(!1).toJS(d.org_netbeans_html_ko4j_$JsCallbacks$(!1)._VM().org_1netbeans_1html_1ko4j_1Knockout$call$ILjava_1lang_1Object_12Ljava_1lang_1Object_12__Ljava_lang_Object_2Lorg_netbeans_html_ko4j_Knockout_2ILjava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2(e,a,c,k))}

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Resulta que incluo si **las propiedades calculadas son de solo lectura por defecto**, se les puede hacer editables especificando el nombre de la función que puede modificar la propiedad dentro de la anotación `@ComputedProperty`; función la cual deberá recibir el **Modelo de datos** como parámetro y los datos que serán usados para mutar el modelo.

HTML:

```
<div>Nombre: <span data-bind="text: firstName, valueUpdate: input"></span></div>
<div>Apellido: <span data-bind="text: lastName, valueUpdate: input"></span></div>
<div class="heading">Hola, <input data-bind="textInput: fullName"/></div>
```

Java:

```
package org.javapro.dukescript;

import net.java.html.json.Model;
import net.java.html.json.ComputedProperty;
import net.java.html.json.Property;
import net.java.html.json.Function;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


@Model (targetId="",className = "WritableComputed", properties = {
    @Property (name = "firstName", type=String.class)
   ,@Property (name = "lastName", type=String.class)
})
class MyClass {

  @ComputedProperty(write="setFullName")
  static String fullName(String firstName, String lastName) {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
  }

  static void setFullName(WritableComputed model, String value) {
    int lastSpacePos = value.lastIndexOf(" ");
            // Ignore values with no space character
            if (lastSpacePos > 0) {
              // Update "firstName"
                model.setFirstName(value.substring(0, lastSpacePos)); 
              // Update "lastName"
                model.setLastName(value.substring(lastSpacePos + 1)); 
            }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
    WritableComputed wc = new WritableComputed("hello","world");
    wc.applyBindings();
  }
}
```